# How to build flutter app on Android device?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, flutter

I just developing Application on Flutter framework.

Now, I just faced some problem, I think that it depends on the Gradle crash.

it doesn't work......till now

So, I attached the error message's image file.

this message came from the command(flutter run -v)

[image: the result of 'flutter run -v]

[the result of 'flutter doctor --verbose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7NeC.png)

So, How can I build this thing???

Comment: First, check with flutter doctor --verbose and make sure all the steps are checked.

Comment: I edited my question.
the result of flutter doctor --verbose.

No issues found

Answer (score 0):

run flutter doctor -v and do all the requisite steps.

Comment: I edited my question. the result of flutter doctor --verbose. No issues found

Comment: Can you try making a new project and copying your code to the new project, I know its kind of "Not what I've asked for", But it's really hard to get problem around gradle and all without knowing the whole project in and out. This is not an optimal solution but what I think you must've edited something. Also please run a new project without copying your file, so you're sure that new project is working